# How do I attach a global event listener?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, events, air, flash-builder

I am working on an AIR application:

The main window is like a dashboard.  With the menu bar, I can open other windows with dashboard details. When I close these, I'd like to refresh the main window.

I tried to use an event listener, but the result is not good. If I open detail windows directly from the main window, I know how to add an event listener - and it works - but I don't know how to do it, if the detail window is opening from the menubar!

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: I edited your wording to make your question a little bit more understandable - I hope I got the meaning correctly...  Can you add an example of what exactly you tried, or why your event listener did not work? Some code would be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen to an object (EventDispatcher) directly by adding an event listener to it, or if the dispatcher object is on the displaylist, such as a Sprite, you could listen at the stage level with the capture parameter set to true.

But the main caveat is that the dispatcher must be on stage for you to catch this event.

Your main window listens to stage (with capture = true):

```
stage.addEventListener("MY_CUSTOM_EVENT", handle_custom_event, true);

private function handle_custom_event(e:Event):void
{
  var sub_window:Object = e.target;
  // do something to your sub_window
}
```

Your sub window can dispatch events like this:

```
dispatchEvent(new Event("MY_CUSTOM_EVENT"));
```

But (ab)using the stage as a message passing infrastructure for custom events in this way is a little messy.  You could consider a more formal message passing architecture if you really want this kind of communication.  Even a static MessageBus class would at least quickly help you identify where you use this in your codebase.  Either way, you'll have to be careful about references and memory leaks.

Comment: I don't think that separate NativeWindows have the same stage.

Comment: Ah, good point.  Too bad I can't vote my own answer down.  =)

Comment: You can ask to have it removed

Comment: Perhaps the question wasn't talking about NativeWindows...  Regardless, all answers are potentially relevant information which is why I didn't ask it to be removed, but I did vote the others answers up.  =)

Answer (score 2):

A Singleton is what you are looking for. Just put an event dispatcher inside and you will be able to listen from everywhere in the application.

A Singleton is like having a unique instance of an object in memory, so anyone modifying a variable inside that object ( or sending events throught ) will be modified for everyone.

Here is an example of code on how to use it.

http://life.neophi.com/danielr/2006/10/singleton_pattern_in_as3.html

**Note: Singletons are powerful and dangerous at the same time, there is a lot of talk about how to use them, please read a little more about that if you are considering building a big project.**

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're performing business logic from a View. Don't do this.  Instead, dispatch an event from each menu rather than directly opening the window from within it. Listen for those events at a higher level, and then you can either directly listen to the new windows you have opened, or you can create a base window Class that exposes a variable of type IEventDispatcher. If you populate that variable with the same event dispatcher, what you wind up with is called an "event bus," and you can listen on that for events.

This architecture requires a little more thought than using a Singleton, but it avoids the tight coupling and other issues you'll run into by introducing one into your project.